# How to use JSON response as an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Here is my response I get from API request:

```
[ 'bookShelf3', 'bookShelf4', 'bookShelf5' ]
```

Here is a part of my code which searches through my mongoDB Databese:

```
const responseToSearchC = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.searchTerm);
  db.collection('subtitle')
    .find({
      series: { $in: ['bookShelf1'] },
      $text: { $search: req.body.searchTerm },
    })
```

I just want to make my code dynamic and instead hard coding ['bookShelf1']
set its value by JSON response.
the problem is the response from API is an object (although it is look like an array) and I cannot replace it with my hard codded array ['bookShelf1']

I tried to stringify it but it didn't work cuz its a string again, and not an array like hardcoded one

Comment: What do you mean the response is an object? Please provide more details about the response. What you've provided here is totally an array.

Comment: since it is a response from API it is an object like = { 0: 'bookShelf3', 1:'bookShelf4', 2: 'bookShelf5'}
also when I use typeof it retunrs object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response is really an object like:

```
{ 0: 'bookShelf3', 1:'bookShelf4', 2: 'bookShelf5'}
```

you can simply utilize the **Object.values()** method which returns all of the object's values as an array.

Here's an example:

```js
let ob={ 0: 'bookShelf3', 1:'bookShelf4', 2: 'bookShelf5'};
console.log(Object.values(ob));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this returns an Enumerable, which isn't *exactly* the same as an Array. TypeScript will complain about this, if you use it. To get an array from an Enumerable just do `Array.from(YOUR_ENUMERABLE)`